# Fast and Golfiest Season 2 Looking for Advice

Tags: discussion, sandbox, challenges, cops-and-robbers

Season 2 is coming! [Season 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263049/cops-fast-and-golfiest-season-1-the-lord-of-the-strings) was fun and relatively well-received, but the main problem was that the scoring system is very broken. Hence I'm looking for advice about how to improve the system so that all participants have around the same difficulty for obtaining scores.

The point is, around the start of the competition cop answers were very quickly cracked. When interest kinda waned, however, it was very easy for the cops to get a ridiculous amount of points.

My current rough idea is to make the cop score a logarithmic function of the time before it is cracked. We should also add some bonus for the fastest guns in the west. However I'm not so sure about details.

**So: any ideas about details for the cops' scoring system?** All pieces of advice are welcome.

One more thing: I'm also looking for proposals for the theme of Season 2 ;-) If you have ideas for a fun topic and a punny name please leave a comment! Thx in advance~

Comment: Just finish the competition when interest wanes. That’s what lots of people did in the old days.